# Getting all subway stations on Android app

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

I'm looking for a way to get all subway stations from a country on Android app but I found nothing on how to do it. Seems there is already a feature request about it (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827961) but it's 4 years old. Is there any another way to get that list please?

Comment: You'd need to find a library or service that provides that information.  Its not built in.  Asking for a library which provides it would be off topic here.

Comment: not asking for a library here neither, just help on how I could do it